# A more rigorous proof on a Bellman-Ford's corollary

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

The following corollary can be found at page 653 of "Introduction to algorithms (3rd edition)"

> Corollary 24.3
>
> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a weighted, directed graph with source vertex $s$
> and a weight function $w: E \to \mathbb{R}$. Then, for each vertex $v
> > \in V$, there is a path from $s$ to $v$ if and only if BELLMAN-FORD
> terminates with $v.d < \infty$ when it is run on $G$.

I have an intuition for the corollary and would formulate its proof as following:

$\rightarrow$: Suppose there are paths from $s$ to $v$, we call the shortest path $p$. The path $p$ is shortest and therefore simple and hence has at most $|V| - 1$ edges. Each edge of the path $p$ will be relaxed by Bellman-Ford, an operation which will only decrease $v.d$. Therefore we can concluse, that $v.d < \infty$ after the algorithm terminates.

Another argument may also include the "Path-relaxation property", which states $v.d = \delta(s, v) < \infty$ after relaxations of all edges of $p$.

$\leftarrow$: Suppose there is no path from $s$ to $v$ but Bellman-Ford terminates with $v.d < \infty$. This would be a contradiction with "No-path property", which states $v.d = \delta(s, v) = \infty$.

I am self-studying the book and there is a lack of feedbacks from tutor, so my question is: would my proof be sufficient in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I think your proof is correct, but there are 2 things that I would like to comment:

1. I think that when you are proving the $\rightarrow$ direction and you say:

> "Each edge of the path $p$ will be relaxed by Bellman-Ford, an operation which will only decrease $v.d$. Therefore we can conclude, that $v.d < \infty$
> after the algorithm terminates."

there is an assumption that a call to RELAX will necessarily decrease $v.d$. But this is not necessarily true, as a call to RELAX can leave $v.d$ untouched. So, you would need to prove that in BELLMAN-FORD there would be a call to RELAX that necessarily decreases $v.d$.
The alternative argument you are proposing (use the "Path-relaxation property") would work fine here, though.

2. Since this is a corollary, I think the authors expected you to use the previous Lemma to solve it (of course, solving it via a different reasoning is ok too).
   In this case, we have Lemma 24.2:

> **Lemma 24.2**
> Let $G = (V, E)$ be a weighted, directed graph with source $s$ and weight function $w: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and assume that $G$ contains no negative-weight cycles that are reachable from $s$. Then, after the $|V| - 1$ iterations of the **for** loop of lines 2-4 of BELLMAN-FORD, we have $v.d = \delta(s, v)$ for all vertices that are reachable from $s$.

We can use it to prove the corollary:

$\rightarrow$: If there is a path from $s$ to $v$, by Lemma 24.2, we have $v.d = \delta(s, v)$, where $\delta(s, v)$ (the shortest path weight from $s$ to $v$) is less than $\infty$ since there is a path.

$\leftarrow$: If BELLMAN-FORD terminates with $v.d < \infty$ when it is run on $G$, by Lemma 24.2 we have that $\delta(s, v) = v.d < \infty$, which by definition of $\delta$ means that there is a path from $s$ to $v$.